# ListView fails to auto-grow in Android

Tags: java, android-layout, listview

I am running into two issues when I populate my ListView. 
1. I do not see the first element. 
2. I only see my List if I hard code the height. How do I avoid this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="?attr/layout_background_color">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/colors_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/colors_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3500dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're putting your `ListView` inside a `NestedScrollView`.

The `ListView` can be in any `Layout` but if you want to put it inside a `NestedScrollView` you will have to do something. Nothing in life is free.

Solution:

Calculate the height programmatically.

[Here](https://medium.com/@skidanolegs/listview-inside-scrollview-solve-the-problem-a06fdff2a4e0) is a link to solve your issue.

OR

Use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` and you won't need to do that *hack* aforementioned.

Comment: Thanks much for the tips Alan! Any idea why I do not see the first element of my List? I see all the remaining members except for the first.